# python pandas - set column value of column based on index and or ID of concatenated dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a concatenated dataframe of at least two concatenated dataframes:

```
i.e. 
df1
  Name | Type | ID
0 Joe     A     1
1 Fred    B     2
2 Mike   Both   3
3 Frank  Both   4

df2
  Name | Type | ID
0 Bill   Both    1
1 Jill   Both    2
2 Mill   B       3
3 Hill   A       4

ConcatDf:
  Name | Type | ID
0 Joe     A     1
1 Fred    B     2
2 Mike   Both   3
3 Frank  Both   4
0 Bill   Both   1
1 Jill   Both   2
2 Mill   B      3
3 Hill   A      4
```

Suppose *after* they are concatenated, I'd like to set `Type` for all records from `df1` to `C` and all records from `df2` to `B`. Is this possible?

The indices of the dataframes can be vastly different sizes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just do it *before* you concatenate?  This seems like an XY problem

Comment: the whole code involves a ton of dictionaries of dataframes loops and slews of processes in the middle involving duplications and mappings and whatnot. With full context, I feel like it would be easiest to just see when the index or ID resets and just assign values based on the end dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], keys = (1,2))

df3.loc[(1), 'Type'] == 'C'
```

When you concat you can assign the df's keys. This will create a multi-index with the keys separating the concatonated df's. Then when you use `.loc` with keys you can use`(` around the key to call the group. In the code above we would change all the Types of df1 (which has a key of 1) to C.

Answer (score 0):

Use `merge` with `indicator=True` to find rows belong to `df1` or `df2`. Next, use `np.where` to assign `A` or `B`.

```
t = concatdf.merge(df1, how='left', on=concatdf.columns.tolist(), indicator=True)
concatdf['Type'] = np.where(t._merge.eq('left_only'), 'B', 'C')


Out[2185]:
    Name Type  ID
0    Joe    C   1
1   Fred    C   2
2   Mike    C   3
3  Frank    C   4
0   Bill    B   1
1   Jill    B   2
2   Mill    B   3
3   Hill    B   4
```